# What art style is used on this Bing (DALL-E) generated image?

Tags: style-identification, graphic-styles

This is an image I created with the Bing image creator, that uses the DALL-E model for image generation.

[image]

How this particular art style can be described?

*Note: I haven't specified any particular style on the prompt for creating this.*

Comment: Most things don't have a specific name. It's usually more appropriate to describe it using a set of works like the ones that you used

Comment: Not all styles of art have specific names. Just use words to describe it. This isn't an example of flat design. The character has shading, and there are gradients in the background.  I would call this a kind of art-poster, perhaps classical Greek god in a comic book superhero style.  These are not specific terms, just descriptive words.  It also kind of reminds me of Soviet era propaganda posters. It's quite a mixture!